# Visual Studio output windows stops displaying anything after a while

Tags: visual-studio

I just edit some code and re-run the application and use the output for mostly debugging. After several runs, when I run the program again it won't display anything.

When I restart the IDE, it works properly. But after a while again output window does not display any text printed by Console.WriteLine.

This behavior is same for VS2013 CE and VS2015 CE.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can show the progression from actual output to no output. Like this it's only guess work. Also I don't think Console.WriteLine is displayd in the Debug section of the output. For this try Debug.WriteLine.

Comment: @Andre I edited my question. For a running session it works or not. It doesn't stop working during a session.

Comment: It's still hard to tell, maybe you started the project without debugging? I assume you know that you can switch what output is displayed (Debug, Built, etc.)?